# Can't update CSV file to BQR

Tags: google-bigquery

I tried to update manually this data sample to BigQuery (after tried to update from Google Cloud, I extracted some rows to detect what's the problem). I met these errors:

Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.

Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 77, but line starting at position:0 contains only 56 columns.

My sample data is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v8jcIKSY7HiOpdc40BFJXACvgX8prWm0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following steps to resolve the issue:

1. Download the file from Google Drive
2. Open the File and Save As "CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) (*.csv)"
3. Open BigQuery and upload CSV file with "Auto detect" schema